# Variable accessible from module in another file only if capitalised

Tags: ruby

**in module.rb**

```
module MyModule
  var = "ruby is magic"
end
```

**magic.rb**

```
require "./module.rb"
puts MyModule::var
```

Error:

```
`<main>': undefined method 'var' for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: "Why does `MyModule::Var` work, but `MyModule::var` does not?". I assume.

Comment: No, you have not asked anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, a "variable" whose name starts with a capital letter is actually a **constant**.

So, when you write code like this:

```
module MyModule
  MyConstant = "ruby is magic"
end
```

You have actually defined a *constant*, which can be accessed anywhere else in the code (assuming this file is loaded):

```
MyModule::MyConstant # => "ruby is magic"
```

On the other hand, if you define a **local variable** (i.e. starting with a lower-case letter):

```
module MyModule
  my_local_variable = "ruby is magic"
end
```

Then this cannot be accessed from outside the scope in which it was defined, because... well, it's a *local* variable!